# Replacing the regex using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace the regex using perl. I have used sed in perl but however, it doesn't seem to work.

### Sample lines to be replaced in a file trans.xml

'fairness' and 'efficiency’

I need to replace 'efficiency’ as ‘efficiency’

I tried the below code,

```
system "sed -e 's/\&\#x0027\;\([a-zA-Z0-9 _]*\)\&\#x2019\;/tooch&/g' trans.xml > tmp.xml";
system "sed -e 's/tooch\&\#x0027\;/\&\#x2018\;/g' tmp.xml > trans.xml"
```

The above sed commands works manually but not from inside the Perl.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Why are you calling sed in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

You're a victim of the double quotes.

Replacing your `system` call with `say` will show you more clearly what's going on:

```
sed -e 's/&#x0027;([a-zA-Z0-9 _]*)&#x2019;/tooch&/g' trans.xml > tmp.xml
sed -e 's/tooch&#x0027;/&#x2018;/g' tmp.xml > trans.xml
```

See what's wrong?  There are no backslashes left.  They've been interpreted by the Perl double quotes, and are not there for `sed` to use.

Your case is a bit tricky to correct, since you already use (and need) the single quotes to pass to `sed`.  You could theoretically escape what's needed one more time, but that's error-prone.  It's much better to use Perl's other single-quoting facilities:

```
system q+sed -e 's/\&\#x0027\;\([a-zA-Z0-9 _]*\)\&\#x2019\;/tooch&/g' trans.xml > tmp.xml+;
system q(sed -e 's/tooch\&\#x0027\;/\&\#x2018\;/g' tmp.xml > trans.xml);
```

I used `+` as a separator on the first line because it happened not to be used in the string itself.  I used plain parentheses in the second line because they were 100% unambiguous there.

Answer (score 0):

A few serious problems:

1. Why are you calling `sed`? Sure, maybe IO is harder to do in `perl`, but `perl` has regexp's inbuilt.

   ```
   use Path::Tiny qw(path);
   my $content = path('trans.xml')->slurp;
   $content =~ s/bar/baz/g;
   $content =~ s/foo/bar/g;
   path('trans.xml')->spew( $content );
   ```

   note: If `trans.xml` is `UTF-8` encoded, all you have to do here is replace `slurp`/`spew` with `slurp_utf8`/`spew_utf8`. VS `sed`, which may be ignorant of unicode.
2. `system` with a string should be avoided where possible, because of many reasons, one is the problem you've experienced: Quoting is hard.

   ```
   system('sed', '-e', $regexp )
   ```

   Is preferred syntax where ever possible. Note you can't use this in conjunction with redirection, but you really don't need to.
3. multiple calls to sed not needed:

   ```
   sed 's/foo/bar/g;s/bar/baz/g'
   ```

   this will apply both expressions.
4. Once #3 is realised, the temporary file is not required:

   ```
   sed -i 's/foo/bar/g;s/bar/baz/g' $file
   ```

   this will modify `$file` **IN PLACE**
5. When using `system`, you probably want to check the return value.

Comment: Thanks. I avoided using sed and used perl substitution instead which is more faster !!